# Is there a way to plot this using seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I'm trying to visualize this using seaborn but unable to find a way.

> My dataframe looks like this:

```
Type    Vmax    Km
W1H     1.1031  34.976545
W1R     1.9014  200.745433
W1X     1.0447  20.796225
```

What I have tried so far:

```
sns.barplot(x='Vmax',y='Type',hue='Km',data=df,orient='h')
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjhAB.png) Results I got:

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/363zA.png) What I would like to have (Something like this):
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need the [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) function from `pandas`. This allows you to obtain a variable that indicates the type of measurment (Km or Vmax) to pass as the `hue` parameter of `seaborn` (you can check out this [paper](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) to read more about this type of "tidy" data representation):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"Type": ["W1H", "W1R", "W1X"], "Vmax": [1.1031, 1.9014, 1.0447],
                  "Km": [34.976545, 200.745433, 20.796225]})

molten = pd.melt(df, id_vars="Type")

# >>> molten
#   Type variable       value
# 0  W1H     Vmax    1.103100
# 1  W1R     Vmax    1.901400
# 2  W1X     Vmax    1.044700
# 3  W1H       Km   34.976545
# 4  W1R       Km  200.745433
# 5  W1X       Km   20.796225

f, ax = plt.subplots()
sbn.barplot(y="Type", x="value", hue="variable", orient="h", data=molten)
```

Output:

[image: d]

However, the scale of the two measurments is rather different, so you can also think about plotting them on two subplots:

```py
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
sbn.barplot(y="Type", x="value", orient="h",
            data=molten.loc[molten["variable"] == "Vmax", :], ax=ax[0], color="black")
sbn.barplot(y="Type", x="value", orient="h",
            data=molten.loc[molten["variable"] == "Km", :], ax=ax[1], color="black")
ax[0].set(xlabel="Vmax", ylabel="")
ax[1].set(xlabel="Km", ylabel="")
f.set_size_inches(10, 5)
```

Output:
[image]